# Typing into UITextView with formatting in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, nsattributedstring

Well this seems silly that it can't be done - you can set a predefined attributed string to be displayed on a text view with formatting, but you can't set general formatting to be applied to live typing on a `UITextView`.

For example, if I do this before typing anything into the text view:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world";
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 50.f;
NSMutableAttributedString *aStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[aStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];
mainTextView.attributedText = aStr;
```

Then formatting displays, and when I edit the text with the keyboard, formatting remains.

However, what if I want to start with a blank `UITextView` and apply formatting to anything the user will type into the view?

I tried setting `string = @""` or `string = @" "`, but neither of those retain formatting. Is there really no way to apply formatting to user input? What's the point then of a UITextView having an attributed string property?

According to the docs, setting the `text` property of the `UITextView` completely wipes off any formatting done by the attributed string. So whatever the solution is, it would have to not directly set `textView.text` property, but rather only tweak with the `attributedText` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what the `typingAttributes` property of the `UITextView` is for.

That is, you'd want to do something like:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 50.f;
mainTextView.typingAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```

Comment: Wowwww this whole time it was that easy? I went through the trouble of creating a new font with the line spacing I wanted :(

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. Is there anything obvious I may have missed outside of this code?

Comment: @Deco: A little late, but just in case other people runs into this: programmatically setting `attributedText` resets the `typingAttributes`. Set `typingAttributes` last.

Answer (score 3):

The key to your problem is this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

What you do with it is keep a private string or attributed string. When this method gets called, you will see the proposed new character(s) that should go in what position and possibly replacing some other characters. By using your private string, or a copy of textView.text, and modifying it, you know have the full string.

You can create a new attributed string or modify your existing one, set it on the textView:

```
textView.attributedString = myNewString;
```

then return NO. Modifying the old string is easy as there are already methods provided by NSString that you let change characters specified with a range by other characters.

Comment: Actually, one issue ... if I use a custom keyboard and manipulate the text via UIKeyInput's insertText or UITextInput's replaceRange:withText: it doesn't call my textView delegate anymore, so the text doesn't get formatted. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have no experience with doing that but suggest consider subclassing UITextView and then do the delegate call after the text is changed. Use an ivar flag to suppress those callbacks from calling themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the delegate methods of `UITextView` to be notified when the use has entered text, then change the text attributes in this method.